# Какой метод лучше, чтобы спрятать например URL-адрес от реверс-инжиниринга: дезинформация или дефицит информации?

Tags: безопасность, защита, reverse-engineering, обфускация

Есть URL-адрес, используемый в DRM приложения.

Допустим, основная задача DRM - это "репорты", поэтому надо, чтобы ее заметили как можно позже, то есть запустили приложение под отладчиком хотя бы один раз не удосужившись "сломать" DRM, при этом она успела собрать и отправить на сервер как можно больше информации о взломщике.

Понятно то, что не стоит делать его таким

```
http://security-server.myapp.com/integrity_check.php
```

И таким:

```
http://security-server.myapp.com/report.php
```

И таким:

```
http://my-poor-and-stupid-security-server.myapp.com/dont_sniff_me_please.php
```

:)

А вот реальный способ, это придумать какую-нибудь более безобидную ерунду вроде:

```
http://security-server.myapp.com/feedback.html
```

А можно и не утруждать себя придумыванием, а написать просто что в голову взбредет:

```
http://security-server.myapp.com/my_realms_heartclick_video.mp4
```

Но есть еще другой способ - не искажать, а уменьшать количество информации, например, так: (здесь получается POST-запрос на index.php, причем этот же домен myapp.com используется и в других HTTP-запросах, которые делает приложение параллельно DRM, а слово "security" убрали)

```
http://server2.myapp.com/
```

Ну, и "до кучи" (здесь и "myapp" убрали и "server", в остальных же HTTP-запросах осталось "myapp"):

```
http://ssr9.com/
```

Или хотя бы ultra light версия, просто убрать расширение:

```
http://server2.myapp.com/feedback
```

Как вы считаете, какой способ эффективнее?

Comment: Просто не надо быть таким жадным

Comment: @Sergey Да, и вообще быть поближе к народу! Провести среди народа голосование: что лучше, разрабатывать уникальный продукт, или пойти с Вами пить пиво в падике... :)

Comment: Конечно пиво. (iii)3 Без вопроса. Никакого голосования не надо. Зачем обфусировать то, что что увидит любой сетевой снифер совершенно без напряга?